# What's the environment variable that Perl looks up for %INC?

Tags: perl

I need to modify that variable to include more directories,

anyone knows the name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[perlrun](http://p3rl.org/perlrun) does in its list of `ENVIRONMENT` variables.

Chances are you're looking for `PERL5LIB`, even though there's a couple of other ways to achieve the same, some of which are mentioned in the above document as well.

Comment: What do you mean by `perlrun` here?

Comment: The document called `perlrun`, which is part of the perl core distribution. Click the link! :-)

Comment: which documents command line switches and environment variables used by perl

Answer (score 6):

I believe you mean [`@INC`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@INC), not [`%INC`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%25INC), and the variable is [`PERL5LIB`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#PERL5LIB).

Answer (score 1):

That's not necessarily the best way to add more directories to your path lookup. You can `push()` new variables onto @INC and you can `use lib 'whatever'`